# Creating tabbed content with JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

I want to create two tabbed divs: "about us" and "contact".what I want specifically is when I click one of them,  a panel retailed to the clicked tab will appear below it, the method I used it to add an event listener to the tabbed divs , then compares the id of the clicked element with the id of the related panel, and then showing the pannel by adding "active class to it", and removing the other pannel by deleting the "active" class. and somehow I couldn't accomplish it, I need some guidance. thanks in advance.

**- HTML CODE :**

```
<div class="tabbed-content">
              <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="list" data-target="#about" >About us</li>
  
                <li class="list" data-target="#contact">Contact</li>
              </ul>

              <div class="pannel" id="about">
                <p>who we are?</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="pannel active" id="contact">
                <p>lets keep in touch</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
              </div>

            </div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
const tabs=document.querySelector(".tabbed-content");
const panels =document.querySelectorAll("pannel");
tabs.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(e){
    if(e.target.className==document.querySelector(".list"))
    {
        const targetpanel=document.querySelector(e.target.dataset.target);
        panels.forEach(function(panel){
            if(panel==targetpanel){
                panel.classList.add("active")
            }
            else{
                panel.classList.remove("active")
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: by the way, the language is "javascript" not "java script" ... the issue is that a className will never equal an HTML element ... `(e.target.className==document.querySelector(".list")`

Comment: I know it xD, "javascript", I made the space because i typed fastly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line should be
`const panels =document.querySelectorAll(".pannel");`
to select by class you add the ".".
here is a possible working version:

```
  const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
  const panels = document.querySelectorAll(".pannel");
  for(let listItem of tabs) {
    listItem.addEventListener("mouseenter", function (e) {
        const dataTarget = e.target.getAttribute('data-target');
        const targetpanel = dataTarget.substr(1);

        panels.forEach(function (panel) {
                if (panel.id == targetpanel) {
                    panel.classList.add("active");
                } else {
                    panel.classList.remove("active");
                }
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I added the "." to the class , but the same result remains.

Comment: its really looks like there's another thing I missed you've edited in your code, I copied your answer and its working, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've actually attached a `mouseenter` listener implying that you are looking for hover functionality. If this is the case it can be accomplished with pure CSS as below.

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}

li:hover .panel {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbed-content">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li>
      <h2 class="list" data-target="#about">About us</h2>
      <div class="panel" id="about">
        <p>who we are?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h2 class="list" data-target="#contact">Contact</h2>
      <div class="panel active" id="contact">
        <p>lets keep in touch</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But if you are indeed looking for click functionality here is a simple working snippet employing `onclick` and `classList.toggle()`.

```js
function toggleActive(e) {
const targetPanelId = e.target.getAttribute('data-target');
  const targetPanel =  document.getElementById(targetPanelId);
  const activePanels = document.getElementsByClassName('active');
  if (activePanels) {
    activePanels[0].classList.toggle('active');
  }
    targetPanel.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none;
}

.panel.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabbed-content">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="list" data-target="about" onclick="toggleActive(event)">About us</li>
    <li class="list" data-target="contact" onclick="toggleActive(event)">Contact</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="panel" id="about">
    <p>who we are?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="panel active" id="contact">
    <p>lets keep in touch</p>
    <p>Cconsectetur adipisicing elit</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, it's really simple with CSS, but I still want it with javascript for learning purpose :).